# Copy a record as new on form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an IR with form and I want to create a new record as a copy of the edited one by a new COPY button.

I set the behavior of this button to redirect to the same page and set all the needed fields as the same as the original (f.e. :P7_SUBJECT to &P7_SUBJECT. , etc.).

There are some LOVs on this form. Some of the LOV-based fields were set correctly, but others didn't (they get the first value of the LOV). I don't find why, and how could set them the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to open the copied record *without* saving the data to the database first. Example has form and report (interactive report) on the sample emp/dept data. Page 4 is the report and page 5 is the form.

- On page 5 add a new hidden item P5_COPY_FROM
- On page 4 add a "copy" column to the report that links to page 5 and sets P5_COPY_FROM to column value #EMPNO#
- On page 5 add a process *before* the process "Initialize Form Employee" of type "Execute code" with source

```
:P5_EMPNO := :P5_COPY_FROM;
```

- On page 5 add a process *after* the process "Initialize Form Employee" of type "Execute code" with source

```
:P5_EMPNO := NULL;
```

This will cause the form to initialize with row you want to copy from, but since the primary key value is reset to NULL, a new record will be created on save.

Comment: Thank you, this method also works fine via form page button.

Answer (score 3):

If "IG" means "Interactive Grid", then I'd suggest you to use what Apex already offers (instead of reinventing the wheel):

- select Interactive Grid's column (either one by one, or all of them at once)
- navigate to their properties on the right-hand side of the screen
- scroll down to "Default" section
- set **Duplicate copies existing value** property ON

  - Help says:

  > Specify whether the column should be defaulted to the existing column value when duplicating the record.
- finally, run the page and

  [image]

---

**[EDIT]** Interactive Report isn't exactly an Interactive Grid ...

Anyway, another suggestion:

- you have an interactive report
- there's the "Edit" icon at the beginning of every row - it lets you *edit* current values by redirecting to a form - use it
- modify the form page by adding the "Copy" button

  - is that what you were saying in the question?
- create a **page process** which will perform that *copying* operation
- how? There's the primary key column, let's call it `P7_ID`; suppose it is set to some sequence's value. Then you'd

  ```
  insert into the_table (id, name, subject)
    select seq.nextval, name, subject
    from the_table
    where id = :P7_ID;
  ```

  In other words, copy row that exists in the database and is identified by `P7_ID`. That option doesn't *suffer* from any *screen values* issues

Comment: Excuse me, it is an IR, not an IG. I do not know this method, but it is not a good way for me, because it gets some value when it will be saved.

Comment: I edited the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: "modify the form page by adding the "Copy" button"
Yes, that is what I did.
Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't want to duplicate the record before users made the modifications that they want. I want to show the same page as when the "New" button was pressed on IR, but fill some fields with data of the sample record (not all). I tried another method when I just delete some fields (f.e. ID, and dates), but I cannot refresh the page to validate some conditions, like change the page read only mode and show/hide buttons.

Comment: The way I see it, values you "see" on the screen aren't in session state so you can't copy those values. How to put them into session state? **Submit** is the most obvious option.